# Get memory error when trying toarray()/todense() with sklearn's CountVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, nlp, text-mining

I am trying to create a document-term matrix using CountVectorizer. My datagram got ~180k row of data. Here is the code I am using:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')

X = cv.fit_transform(df.content) #X is a scipy sparse matrix
data_dtm = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=cv.get_feature_names())
```

Here I'm getting this error:
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 70.1 GiB for an array with shape (180399, 52142) and data type int64

I tried the same thing with todense() as well as:

```
data_dtm = pd.DataFrame(X.todense(), columns=cv.get_feature_names())
```

But still the same. I know the problem is with the **toarray()/todense()**
I found several similar questions about applying these functions on **sparse matrices** but couldn't get an effective answer. For example, using **asarray()** was one of suggestions which doesn't work for me!

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Looks like `x` is a scipy sparse matrix.  You could verify it by displaying `type(x)`.  The error tells us that there isn't space in your computer to make a dense, `ndarray` equivalent.  Such array will be too big (70GB).  The fact that you also try `todense` and `np.asarray` tells me you either don't understand the issue, or you are refusing to accept that it is an problem.  There isn't a fix!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, I see there is a need of ~70GB but was hoping to find an efficient way to address it. That's a bummer for working on text mining/nlp problems.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to do this in multiple chunks?!

Comment: What is `180399 *52142*8`?  That's the space, in bytes, required such an array.

Comment: There are plenty of ML algorithms that can take sparse inputs. Pandas also can convert from scipy sparse format to its own sparse dtype columns, if for some reason you really need a pandas frame.